# Algorithm for compressing small files (345 Bytes)

Tags: algorithm, compression

I'm looking for a software that can losslessy compress a small amount of  noisy data; example:

```
ZmNiYWNma3F5gYqSmqCkpqenpKGdmJONiIN/e3d1c3FxcXFxcnN0dXZ3eXp7fHx9fn5/gIGDhISFhYWFhIOCgYGAgICBgoOEhYeIiYmJiYiGhIF+fHl3dHNyc3N1d3p9gIOGiYuMjY2NjIuKiIeFg4GAfnx7eXl4eHl5enx9fn5/gICAgYGBgYGBgYGBgoKDhISEhISEhIOCgoGAgH9/fn5+fn5/gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAf39/gICBgoOFhoeIiIiIiIeGhYOCgH99fHt6enp6e3x9foCAgoKDg4ODgoKBgH59fHt7e3t8fX5/gIKDhIWFhoaGhoaFhISDgoKBgQ==
```

Original data: 345B (100%),
gzip: 280B (81%),
bzip2: 289B (84%),
lzop: 415B (120%),

Are there any other methods I should try?

Comment: Lol... lzop really increased the size? That is funny.

Comment: Not the right place to ask for tool recommendations.

Comment: What is your target size? ie. what would you accept as "good enough"?

Comment: I'm currently at 64 to 96 bytes for this and similar data. See my answer below.

Comment: I've got an adaptive Shannon-Fano coder that also compresses your string here to 280 bytes. I suggest you go that route, or adaptive Huffman.

Comment: I also have an experimental compressor, which - in addition to character distribution - looks for common phrases, much like the various LZ variants, and it can encode the above in 273 bytes, so not much of an improvement over pure character-based approaches.

Comment: I got to 108/109 bytes for that particular file using a huffman compression of the delta values.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Very cool.

Comment: Going to write up the code into something that looks a bit more ... hum ... professional as this is just a linqpad mockup :)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Did you decode(64) the data first? See my answer for the underlying data). The decoded data has much smaller delta values.

Comment: Yes, I did. Base 64 decode, then convert to delta bytes, then huffman compression.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Better hurry if you want to post it here before the question gets closed :)

Comment: OK, posted it as an answer + link to my Mercurial repo with the solution files. These classes need heavy refactoring and probably a bit of optimization, it's getting a bit late here so I skimped on the unit-tests and final tuneups :) Final tally with all bugs fixed was 118 bytes for the test input.

Comment: Second-order delta encoding yielded final results at 77 bytes. Depending on the variation of the input files this might be something that needs more data to be sane to do on all the files. If you can provide more input files (a dropbox full of them for instance) then perhaps even better solutions could be found.

Comment: 76 bytes. Had a vital bug in the code, huffman nodes needs to be resorted after combining two nodes which I had forgotten. Discovered this when I added a test that tried to compress the full "Mary had a little lamb" text and it failed to reduce the size, which it easily should. Code in answer and repo has been fixed and a few more tests have been written. G'night.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the data is [`Base64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded (every 3 bytes become 4 bytes), the first step would be to decode it (the compressed data will be binary anyway):

```
344 bytes -> 256 bytes
```

Then, a simple test with standard winzip here shows a compression to `170 bytes` (`COMP_DEFLATE` block). You should get about the same with gzip/zlib.

This could probably made somewhat smaller with a higher compression factor.

Compressing the original data gives 243 bytes (data block inside the .zip file, the full zip file is 359 bytes, but you don't need all that extra data).

So, using [zlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib) on the decoded data, should compress that to **±170 bytes**.

---

Looking at the decoded data, an even better compression would be possible. But that depends on the other data having the same structure.

Hex dump of the **decoded data** (a lot of values are repeating, or only changing slightly):

```
66 63 62 61 63 66 6B 71 79 81 8A 92 9A A0 A4 A6
A7 A7 A4 A1 9D 98 93 8D 88 83 7F 7B 77 75 73 71
71 71 71 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 79 7A 7B 7C 7C 7D
7E 7E 7F 80 81 83 84 84 85 85 85 85 84 83 82 81
81 80 80 80 81 82 83 84 85 87 88 89 89 89 89 88
86 84 81 7E 7C 79 77 74 73 72 73 73 75 77 7A 7D
80 83 86 89 8B 8C 8D 8D 8D 8C 8B 8A 88 87 85 83
81 80 7E 7C 7B 79 79 78 78 79 79 7A 7C 7D 7E 7E
7F 80 80 80 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 81 82 82 83
84 84 84 84 84 84 84 83 82 82 81 80 80 7F 7F 7E
7E 7E 7E 7E 7F 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80
80 80 80 80 7F 7F 7F 80 80 81 82 83 85 86 87 88
88 88 88 88 87 86 85 83 82 80 7F 7D 7C 7B 7A 7A
7A 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E 80 80 82 82 83 83 83 83 82 82
81 80 7E 7D 7C 7B 7B 7B 7B 7C 7D 7E 7F 80 82 83
84 85 85 86 86 86 86 86 85 84 84 83 82 82 81 81
```

Only after a quick look: it should be possible to reach about 2 to 3 bits per byte on average, resulting in **64** to **96 bytes**.

---

### A closer look at the data:

[image]

Most values don't change that much. If all data is similar to this, a high compression rate could be achieved using some custom code. For example, **the differences could be stored in 1, 2, 3 or 4 bits** depending on the block of data (4 bits only needed for the first data points). Another approach, instead of full custom code, would be to **compress the differences (delta values)** with an existing algorithm ([zlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zlib), [Huffman coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding), and others).

**Decimal values with 2 rounds of delta-encoding**:

```
102        
99    -3    
98    -1    2
97    -1    0
99     2    3
102    3    1
107    5    2
113    6    1
121    8    2
129    8    0
138    9    1
146    8   -1
154    8    0
160    6   -2
164    4   -2
166    2   -2
167    1   -1
167    0   -1
164   -3   -3
161   -3    0
157   -4   -1
152   -5   -1
147   -5    0
141   -6   -1
136   -5    1
131   -5    0
127   -4    1
123   -4    0
119   -4    0
117   -2    2
115   -2    0
113   -2    0
113    0    2
113    0    0
113    0    0
113    0    0
114    1    1
115    1    0
116    1    0
117    1    0
118    1    0
119    1    0
121    2    1
122    1   -1
123    1    0
124    1    0
124    0   -1
125    1    1
126    1    0
126    0   -1
127    1    1
128    1    0
129    1    0
131    2    1
132    1   -1
132    0   -1
133    1    1
133    0   -1
133    0    0
133    0    0
132   -1   -1
131   -1    0
130   -1    0
129   -1    0
129    0    1
128   -1   -1
128    0    1
128    0    0
129    1    1
130    1    0
131    1    0
132    1    0
133    1    0
135    2    1
136    1   -1
137    1    0
137    0   -1
137    0    0
137    0    0
136   -1   -1
134   -2   -1
132   -2    0
129   -3   -1
126   -3    0
124   -2    1
121   -3   -1
119   -2    1
116   -3   -1
115   -1    2
114   -1    0
115    1    2
115    0   -1
117    2    2
119    2    0
122    3    1
125    3    0
128    3    0
131    3    0
134    3    0
137    3    0
139    2   -1
140    1   -1
141    1    0
141    0   -1
141    0    0
140   -1   -1
139   -1    0
138   -1    0
136   -2   -1
135   -1    1
133   -2   -1
131   -2    0
129   -2    0
128   -1    1
126   -2   -1
124   -2    0
123   -1    1
121   -2   -1
121    0    2
120   -1   -1
120    0    1
121    1    1
121    0   -1
122    1    1
124    2    1
125    1   -1
126    1    0
126    0   -1
127    1    1
128    1    0
128    0   -1
128    0    0
129    1    1
129    0   -1
129    0    0
129    0    0
129    0    0
129    0    0
129    0    0
129    0    0
129    0    0
130    1    1
130    0   -1
131    1    1
132    1    0
132    0   -1
132    0    0
132    0    0
132    0    0
132    0    0
132    0    0
131   -1   -1
130   -1    0
130    0    1
129   -1   -1
128   -1    0
128    0    1
127   -1   -1
127    0    1
126   -1   -1
126    0    1
126    0    0
126    0    0
126    0    0
127    1    1
128    1    0
128    0   -1
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
128    0    0
127   -1   -1
127    0    1
127    0    0
128    1    1
128    0   -1
129    1    1
130    1    0
131    1    0
133    2    1
134    1   -1
135    1    0
136    1    0
136    0   -1
136    0    0
136    0    0
136    0    0
135   -1   -1
134   -1    0
133   -1    0
131   -2   -1
130   -1    1
128   -2   -1
127   -1    1
125   -2   -1
124   -1    1
123   -1    0
122   -1    0
122    0    1
122    0    0
122    0    0
123    1    1
124    1    0
125    1    0
126    1    0
128    2    1
128    0   -2
130    2    2
130    0   -2
131    1    1
131    0   -1
131    0    0
131    0    0
130   -1   -1
130    0    1
129   -1   -1
128   -1    0
126   -2   -1
125   -1    1
124   -1    0
123   -1    0
123    0    1
123    0    0
123    0    0
124    1    1
125    1    0
126    1    0
127    1    0
128    1    0
130    2    1
131    1   -1
132    1    0
133    1    0
133    0   -1
134    1    1
134    0   -1
134    0    0
134    0    0
134    0    0
133   -1   -1
132   -1    0
132    0    1
131   -1   -1
130   -1    0
130    0    1
129   -1   -1
129    0    1
```

Comment: Doing delta-encoding twice yielded even better results.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - 77 bytes, not bad at all!  +1 :)

Comment: Since the nb of symbols is quite reduced after delta-encoding, some probabilities will become high enough to start generating distortion with Huffman, reducing its compression effectiveness. Try something more precise, such as an arithmetic coder, or [FSE](https://github.com/Cyan4973/FiniteStateEntropy)

Comment: @Cyan - That would be interesting to test. But maybe we need some more data before doing that (the provided data might as well be some random test data).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete set of classes that can be used to compress this data with the following approach:

1. First Base64 decode the string to get bytes (345 -> 256 bytes)
2. Then delta-encode the bytes (meaning, subtract one byte from the previous, storing the results)
3. Another round of delta-encoding (but 3 was worse than 2)
4. Then compress the deltas using Huffman compression

This approach got down to 76 bytes including the necessary overhead to decompress later on.

A full Mercurial repository with the code can be found [here](https://lassevk.kilnhg.com/Code/StackOverflow/answers/SO34796676).

**Note!** The code likely contains bugs around edge-cases such as empty or near-empty inputs. A suite of unit-tests can be found in the above linked repository but more testing is likely needed in order to trust this code for production usage.

Test program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputString = "ZmNiYWNma3F5gYqSmqCkpqenpKGdmJONiIN/e3d1c3FxcXFxcnN0dXZ3eXp7fHx9fn5/gIGDhISFhYWFhIOCgYGAgICBgoOEhYeIiYmJiYiGhIF+fHl3dHNyc3N1d3p9gIOGiYuMjY2NjIuKiIeFg4GAfnx7eXl4eHl5enx9fn5/gICAgYGBgYGBgYGBgoKDhISEhISEhIOCgoGAgH9/fn5+fn5/gICAgICAgICAgICAgICAf39/gICBgoOFhoeIiIiIiIeGhYOCgH99fHt6enp6e3x9foCAgoKDg4ODgoKBgH59fHt7e3t8fX5/gIKDhIWFhoaGhoaFhISDgoKBgQ==";
    byte[] original = Convert.FromBase64String(inputString);

    Console.WriteLine($"Original String: {inputString.Length}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Original bytes: {original.Length}");

    byte[] deltaEncoded = DeltaEncoderDecoder.Encode(original, 2);
    byte[] compressed = HuffmanCompression.Compress(deltaEncoded);
    Console.WriteLine($"Compressed bytes: {compressed.Length}");

    byte[] deltaDecoded = HuffmanCompression.Decompress(compressed);
    byte[] decompressed = DeltaEncoderDecoder.Decode(deltaDecoded, 2);
    Console.WriteLine($"Decompressed bytes: {decompressed.Length}");

    Console.WriteLine($"Decompressed == original: {decompressed.Length == original.Length && Enumerable.Range(0, original.Length).All(index => original[index] == decompressed[index])}");
}
```

Output:

```
Original String: 344
Original bytes: 256
Compressed bytes: 76
Decompressed bytes: 256
Decompressed == original: True
```

Here are the necessary classes to both compress and decompress the data:

```
public static class HuffmanCompression
{
    internal const byte CompressedSignature = 255;
    internal const byte UncompressedSignature = 0;

    [NotNull]
    public static byte[] Compress([NotNull] byte[] input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        if (input.Length == 0)
            return input;

        var rootNode = GetNodesFromRawInput(input);
        var bitStrings = GetBitStringsFromTree(rootNode);

        var output = new MemoryStream(input.Length);
        var writer = new BitStreamWriter(output);

        writer.Write(CompressedSignature);
        writer.Write(input.Length);
        WriteNodes(writer, rootNode);
        WriteStrings(writer, bitStrings, input);
        writer.Flush();

        if (output.Length < input.Length + 1)
            return output.ToArray();

        return EncodeAsUncompressed(input);
    }

    [NotNull]
    private static byte[] EncodeAsUncompressed([NotNull] byte[] input)
    {
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        output.WriteByte(UncompressedSignature);
        output.Write(input, 0, input.Length);
        return output.ToArray();
    }

    private static void WriteStrings([NotNull] BitStreamWriter writer, [NotNull] string[] bitStrings, [NotNull] byte[] input)
    {
        foreach (byte value in input)
        {
            Assume(bitStrings[value] != null);
            foreach (char bitChar in bitStrings[value])
                writer.Write(bitChar == '1');
        }
    }

    private static void WriteNodes([NotNull] BitStreamWriter writer, [NotNull] Node node)
    {
        if (node.Left == null)
        {
            writer.Write(false);
            writer.Write(node.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Assume(node.Right != null);

            writer.Write(true);
            WriteNodes(writer, node.Left);
            WriteNodes(writer, node.Right);
        }
    }

    [NotNull, ItemNotNull]
    private static string[] GetBitStringsFromTree([NotNull] Node node)
    {
        var result = new string[256];
        TraverseToGetBitStringsFromTree(node, string.Empty, result);
        return result;
    }

    private static void TraverseToGetBitStringsFromTree([NotNull] Node node, [NotNull] string prefix, [NotNull, ItemNotNull] string[] dictionary)
    {
        if (node.Left != null)
        {
            Assume(node.Right != null);

            TraverseToGetBitStringsFromTree(node.Left, prefix + "0", dictionary);
            TraverseToGetBitStringsFromTree(node.Right, prefix + "1", dictionary);
        }
        else
            dictionary[node.Value] = prefix;
    }

    [NotNull]
    private static Node GetNodesFromRawInput([NotNull] byte[] input)
    {
        var occurances = new int[256];
        foreach (byte value in input)
            occurances[value]++;

        var nodes = new List<Node>(256);
        for (int index = 0; index < 256; index++)
            if (occurances[index] > 0)
                nodes.Add(new Node
                {
                    Occurances = occurances[index],
                    Value = (byte)index
                });

        while (nodes.Count > 1)
        {
            nodes.Sort((n1, n2) =>
            {
                Assume(n1 != null && n2 != null);

                return n1.Occurances.CompareTo(n2.Occurances);
            });

            Assume(nodes[0] != null && nodes[1] != null);

            nodes[0] = new Node
            {
                Left = nodes[0],
                Right = nodes[1],
                Occurances = nodes[0].Occurances + nodes[1].Occurances
            };
            nodes.RemoveAt(1);
        }

        Assume(nodes[0] != null);

        return nodes[0];
    }

    [NotNull]
    public static byte[] Decompress([NotNull] byte[] input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));
        if (input.Length == 0)
            return input;

        if (input[0] != CompressedSignature)
            return DecodeUncompressed(input);

        var reader = new BitStreamReader(new MemoryStream(input));
        reader.ReadByte(); // skip signature

        int length = reader.ReadInt32();
        var rootNode = ReadNodes(reader);
        var output = new byte[length];
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index++)
            output[index] = DecompressOneByte(reader, rootNode);

        return output;
    }

    private static byte DecompressOneByte([NotNull] BitStreamReader reader, [NotNull] Node node)
    {
        while (node.Left != null)
        {
            if (reader.ReadBit())
                node = node.Right;
            else
                node = node.Left;

            Assume(node != null);
        }

        return node.Value;
    }

    [NotNull]
    private static Node ReadNodes([NotNull] BitStreamReader reader)
    {
        if (reader.ReadBit())
            return new Node
            {
                Left = ReadNodes(reader),
                Right = ReadNodes(reader)
            };

        return new Node
        {
            Value = reader.ReadByte()
        };
    }

    [NotNull]
    private static byte[] DecodeUncompressed([NotNull] byte[] input)
    {
        return input.Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
}

public class BitStreamReader
{
    [NotNull]
    private readonly MemoryStream _Source;

    private byte _Buffer;
    private int _InBuffer;

    public BitStreamReader([NotNull] MemoryStream source)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

        _Source = source;
    }

    public bool ReadBit()
    {
        if (_InBuffer == 0)
            FillBuffer();

        return (_Buffer & BitStreamConstants.BitMasks[8 - _InBuffer--]) != 0;
    }

    public byte ReadByte()
    {
        if (_InBuffer == 8)
        {
            _InBuffer = 0;
            return _Buffer;
        }

        return (byte)((ReadBit() ? 128 : 0) | (ReadBit() ? 64 : 0) | (ReadBit() ? 32 : 0) | (ReadBit() ? 16 : 0) | (ReadBit() ? 8 : 0) | (ReadBit() ? 4 : 0) | (ReadBit() ? 2 : 0) | (ReadBit() ? 1 : 0));
    }

    public int ReadInt32()
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (ReadBit())
            result |= ReadByte();
        if (ReadBit())
            result |= ReadByte() << 8;
        if (ReadBit())
            result |= ReadByte() << 16;
        if (ReadBit())
            result |= ReadByte() << 24;
        return result;
    }

    private void FillBuffer()
    {
        int value = _Source.ReadByte();
        if (value < 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Read past end of source stream");

        _Buffer = (byte)value;
        _InBuffer = 8;
    }
}

public class BitStreamWriter
{
    [NotNull]
    private readonly MemoryStream _Target;

    private byte _Buffer;
    private int _InBuffer;

    public BitStreamWriter([NotNull] MemoryStream target)
    {
        if (target == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));

        _Target = target;
    }

    public void Flush()
    {
        if (_InBuffer == 0)
            return;

        _Target.WriteByte(_Buffer);
        _Buffer = 0;
        _InBuffer = 0;
    }

    public void Write(bool bit)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            if (bit)
                _Buffer = (byte)(_Buffer | 1 << (7 - _InBuffer));
            if (++_InBuffer == 8)
                Flush();
        }
    }

    public void Write(byte value)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < 8; index++)
            Write((value & BitStreamConstants.BitMasks[index]) != 0);
    }

    public void Write(int value)
    {
        byte b0 = (byte)(value & 0xff);
        byte b1 = (byte)((value >> 8) & 0xff);
        byte b2 = (byte)((value >> 16) & 0xff);
        byte b3 = (byte)((value >> 24) & 0xff);

        Write(b0 != 0);
        if (b0 != 0)
            Write(b0);

        Write(b1 != 0);
        if (b1 != 0)
            Write(b1);

        Write(b2 != 0);
        if (b2 != 0)
            Write(b2);

        Write(b3 != 0);
        if (b3 != 0)
            Write(b3);
    }
}

internal static class BitStreamConstants
{
    [NotNull]
    public static readonly byte[] BitMasks = { 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 };

    public const byte CompressedSignature = 255;
}

public static class DeltaEncoderDecoder
{
    [NotNull]
    public static byte[] Encode([NotNull] byte[] input, int iterations)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

        var output = new byte[input.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 0, output, 0, input.Length);

        while (iterations-- > 0)
        {
            byte previous = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < output.Length; index++)
            {
                byte current = output[index];
                output[index] = (byte)(current - previous);
                previous = current;
            }
        }

        return output;
    }

    [NotNull]
    public static byte[] Decode([NotNull] byte[] input, int iterations)
    {
        if (input == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(input));

        var output = new byte[input.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(input, 0, output, 0, input.Length);

        while (iterations-- > 0)
        {
            byte previous = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < output.Length; index++)
            {
                output[index] = (byte)(previous + output[index]);
                previous = output[index];
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: This deserves at least a `+200 bounty` :)

Comment: The code had a vital flaw, it was missing a sort call. Adding this now.

Comment: Wasn't it _getting late_ ? :)

Comment: Couldn't leave buggy code with less than 100% code coverage out there in the open. :) Bugfix got total down to 76 bytes as well :)

Comment: But now I'm really done for tonight, mercurial repo fully updates with latest changes, including a more tests, still likely to need more edge-case testing though and probably some optimizations as well though decompression speed should probably be quite good.

Comment: @Lasse : What if the last stage (huffman) is replaced by a more precise arithmetic coder or [FSE](https://github.com/Cyan4973/FiniteStateEntropy) ?

Comment: I have little experience with arithmetic coders except to read about them. Judging by what I know from what I've read it would likely yield about 20-30% better compression ratio though I suspect we're in edge-case country with such small files. Would assume something around 50-60 bytes total. But again, I have no experience with FSE or similar coders. Feel free to download my repo from the linked site and dump the bytes to a file before the huffman compression and see if something else can produce better compression though, should be easy to do.

Comment: In face, here is that file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/674jp0p6r58ej4d/test.dat?dl=1 - If you can compile FSE as an executable you should be able to just compress it directly to see the final results.

Comment: But I really need to go to bed now, let me know in the comments what you think/found out.

Comment: Just tested your test file. It's not a lot better with FSE. 
Sure, It compresses a bit better (64 bytes) but then it's required to make a good (ie specific) effort to optimize headers, at the very least take into consideration the 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, etc. frequency order.